# How to align these textboxes properly?

Tags: php, html

I have problem trying to align these textboxes properly. When I tried float: left/right. They become awkward like Label went to right side and textboxes moved to left side.

[image: My current form]

Here is my current style for html

```
<style>


.registrationform 
{
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 600px;
    border: solid 3px red;   
}

</style>
```

Here is my current [body]

```
<div class = "registrationform">

        <h2>Preschool Package Registration Form</h2>
        <br><br>

        <form action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method = "post">
        
        Parent(s) Name(s) <span style="color: red;">*</span>: 
        <input type = "text" name = "parentname" value="<?php echo $parentname;?>">
        <span id = "warning" style="color: red;" > <?php echo $parentError;?></span>
        <br><br>

        Email Address <span style="color: red;">*</span>: 
        <input type = "text" name = "email" value = "<?php echo $email;?>">
        <span id = "warning" style="color: red;"> <?php echo $emailError;?></span>
        <br><br>

        Student's Name <span style="color: red;">*</span>: 
        <input type = "text" name = "student" value = "<?php echo $student;?>">
        <span id = "warning" style="color: red;"> <?php echo $studentError;?></span>
        <br><br>

        Student's Gender <span style="color: red;">*</span>: 
        <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "Female">Female
        <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "Male">Male
        <span id = "warning" style="color: red;"> <?php echo $genderError;?></span>
        <br><br>
```

There are more but the rest are pretty much the same like what I posted here.

Comment: You can use `grid layout`

Answer (score 1):

You can use grids, just make the form element a grid. To achieve this, you need to split each your form field in to parts, the label and the input.
Each one needs to be wrapped by an element, you can wrap the label with the `<label>` tag and the input with the error message with a `div`.
See the example :

```css
.registrationform {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 600px;
    border: solid 3px red;   
}

.registrationform form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="registrationform">
  <h2>Preschool Package Registration Form</h2>
  <br><br>

  <form action="#" method="post">

    <label>Parent(s) Name(s) <span style="color: red;">*</span>:</label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="parentname" value="<?php echo $parentname;?>">
      <span style="color: red;"><?php echo $parentname;?></span>

    </div>

    <label>Email Address <span style="color: red;">*</span>:</label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
      <span style="color: red;"> <?php echo $emailError;?></span>
    </div>


    <label>Student's Name <span style="color: red;">*</span>:</label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="student" value="<?php echo $student;?>">
      <span style="color: red;"> <?php echo $studentError;?></span>
    </div>

    <label>Student's Gender <span style="color: red;">*</span>:</label>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male
      <span style="color: red;"> <?php echo $genderError;?></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

PS : I removed some properties of your code to make it work in vanilla html & css, you can adapt this example to your case. Also, you should put the `for` property on the label so as to make it clickable.